# Line by line input via java console

Tags: java, command-line, input, console

Please help me to input by line by line via java console. Now i can give input only as one line. How to give multiple inputs in line by line??

Comment: Use loop? Read multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

```
      InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);

      String CurLine = ""; // Line read from standard in

      while (!(CurLine.equals("quit"))){
          CurLine = in.readLine();

          if (!(CurLine.equals("quit"))){
              System.out.println("You typed: " + CurLine);
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scanner and loop through to ask for multiple times.

For example

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
while (stdin.hasNext()) {
//Get input and do your logic.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but...

```
 final List<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
 final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      System.out.print("> ");
      inputs.add(in.next());
 }
 System.out.println(inputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *new* Console class:

```
Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(console.reader());
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        // Do something with your line
    }
}
```

End the input by pressing `^Z` (control-Z) followed by `ENTER`.

It has one caveat and that is that the `console` can be null inside an IDE. Try it from the command-line and you should be fine:

```
java path.to.my.MainClass
```